# Replace multiple strings altogether

Tags: java

I have this situation where I have to replace multiple strings with a single string value.

```
String replacedString = Information.replace("", "Resident Referral").
replace("", "Return Visitor");

Referral                 
Resident Referral          
Resident Referrral  -------------- Replace all three with Resident Referral

Return visitor
Return Visitor
Return Vistitor
Return Vistor    ----------------- Replace all four with Return Visitor
```

Replace the string values where **Refer** is common with Resident Referral and replace the string values where **Return** is common with Return Visitor.

How can I get this done?

Comment: Where are you getting the input from? A file?

Comment: Sorry, you start writing code; and when you have a specific question about code, you are welcome to ask that here. As of now, your question doesn't really fit here.

Comment: I am stuck on these lines @ GhostCat otherwise I have my code all figured out.

Comment: Have a look at the `replace` method of the `String` class. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: And have a look at the [help] esp. on [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want *Referral, Resident Referral* and *Resident Referrral* to be replaced with **Resident Referral**, as well as *Return visitor*, *Return Visitor*, *Return Vistitor* and *Return Vistor* to be replaced with **Return Visitor**

The way to go is to use [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) in order to match all cases with one expression.
An example for the Regular Expressions to use would be `Information.replaceAll("(Resident )?Refer{1,3}al", "Resident Referral")` for the replacing each case with *Resident Referral* and `Information.replaceAll("Return [Vv]isi?ti?t?or", "Return Visitor")` for replacing each case with *Return Visitor*.

Please note that my knowledge on Regular Expressions is quite basic and these might not be the most efficient or beautiful ways of expressing these cases in Regular Expressions.

Moreover, I have found that [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) is quite a nice website to get yourself familiar with the usage of Regular Expressions, as well as practicing with Regular Expressions yourself.

Comment: Exactly what is desired, although it does not throw an error it also does not make any difference.

Comment: Could you eloborate on that? When should it throw an error?

Comment: The snippet runs well with the code you provided but it does not change/replace the values designated. The values to be replaced remain the same.`Information.replace("Return [Vv]isi?ti?t?or", "Return Visitor").replace("(Resident )?Refer{1,3}al", "Resident Referral");` Thanks for trying Max.

Comment: My bad, since it a Regular Expression, the function `replaceAll` should be used instead of `replace` (See the JavaDocs for both [String.replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) and [String.replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))) You notice that `replace` takes a char or CharSequence whereas `replaceAll` takes a regular expression.

Comment: Appreciate the help Max. New to Java and learning as I am going.

Comment: My pleasure, good luck on learning! Make sure to check [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) though, might come in handy in future applications.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136423/discussion-between-max-van-deursen-and-pythoner).